# Use of unicodeplots() in julia

Tags: plot, julia

I'm trying to use unicodeplots() to generate plots in julia.
My first version of code is

```
using Plots
unicodeplots()
plt = plot(x,y) #x,y are same length of vectors
display(plt)
```

What I got is

```
   Warning: Error requiring `UnicodePlots` from `Plots`
 exception = (LoadError("/Users/.julia/packages/Plots/gzYVM/src/backends/unicodeplots.jl", 276, LoadError("/Usersg/.julia/packages/Plots/gzYVM/src/backends/unicodeplots.jl", 314, UndefVarError(:FileIO))), Union{Ptr{Nothing}, Base.InterpreterIP}[Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000105799b1f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c80d3, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e41a3, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e3083, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b9fdb, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b7577, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b74df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057b7deb, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e35d7, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e414b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e4eef, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011d5968e7, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016d6c0377, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016d6cc01b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016d6cc077, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057bcd17, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bf000cb, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bf00143, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057ca21b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8a03, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c9053, Base.InterpreterIP in top-level CodeInfo for Plots at statement 8, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e427f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e4eef, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bef407f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bef409f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000128fb478b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bee807b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bee808f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057ca21b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8767, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8c8b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8403, Base.InterpreterIP in MethodInstance for Requires.withpath(::Any, ::String) at statement 10, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bedc097, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bedc12b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057bcd17, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bed0073, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bed00fb, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057ca21b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8a03, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8403, Base.InterpreterIP in MethodInstance for Requires.loadpkg(::Base.PkgId) at statement 6, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057bcd17, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000107bb0433, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016bc940d7, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be8839b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be88837, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e49f3, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e3f03, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c892b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c9053, Base.InterpreterIP in top-level CodeInfo for Main at statement 0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e427f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e4eef, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be641db, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be70143, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be7c00f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be7c01f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057ca21b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c8a03, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057c9053, Base.InterpreterIP in top-level CodeInfo for Main at statement 0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e427f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e414b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057e4eef, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011a77026b, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011a77c043, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be45167, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000016be45eaf, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057bcd17, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011a4a0443, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011a4b8067, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000011a4b8073, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057afc63, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001057ce9cb])
    └ @ Requires /Users/.julia/packages/Requires/Z8rfN/src/require.jl:51
```

And I can only get Plots.UnicodePlotsBackend()

My second version of code is

```
using Plots
using unicodeplots
unicodeplots()
plt = plot(x,y) #x,y are same length of vectors
display(plt)
```

What I got is **WARNING: using UnicodePlots.xlabel! in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier.**

And I still got Plots.UnicodePlotsBackend()

What might be issue of my code?

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. What version of Julia and Plots are you running?

Comment: `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Project.toml`
⌃ [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.36.1.  Julia version: Julia Version 1.8.1

Comment: I'm trying if I get the same error with the same version of Julia.

Comment: I can tell you that Julia 1.8.1 with Plots v1.38.2 works fine. I'm now reverting to Plots@1.36.1 to see if I get the same error.

Comment: Is it because I'm using jupyter notebook?

Comment: I finally confirm that also with Plots 1.36.1 I do not get the same issue.

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: I changed to vscode, and I got warning " Warning: _display is not defined for this backend." And there is still no plot showing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of ideas.

1. Usually when you get the `Warning:... in Module Main conflicts...` that means that there are two packages with the same function name. For example, you might have Gadfly (or another plotting package that has the `plot()` function) loaded.

One thing that sometimes works is to use the name of the package before the function, with a `.` in the middle. For example, I might write `Plots.plot` or `Gadfly.plot`.

Honestly, it might just be that having only one plotting package loaded will fix all your problems. Jupyter Notebook should not be the issue, but if you're concerned about missing output (only seeing the Backend output and not the plot) in a cell in which you expect a plot, just split the plotting commands and the `using` or `unicodeplots()` commands into different cells.

2. There isn't a package called unicodeplots. HOWEVER, there is one called UnicodePlots. I've found that it works nicely. If you can't get Plots.jl's version to work, give it a try. It's really made for the REPL, and it's cool because I don't think another plotting package lets you plot from there.

Comment: or you can import one package with the keyword `using` and the other with `import`. The latter does not bring the function names to the global namespace

Comment: I have changed to vscode and only used Plots package, but the warning still remains.